# What is the address of a ServiceHost if I specify the parameters instead of using config file

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm following this MSDN How-To: [host and run a basic windows WCF service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-host-and-run-a-basic-wcf-service)

In this chapter a service is hosted by providing parameters instead of reading the values from the configuration file.

This is probably not a scenario I will use, I just want to understand what happens.

My problem: the service runs, but I can't see it in a browser.

Previous steps:
 - Visual Studio 2017, newest .NET, C# v. 7.0
 - Created new Solution; added new Project: WCF library
 - Result: one DLL with 3 source files: 1 Interface with the Service Contract, one implementation of this interface and one app.config
 - This app.config is used when debugging the dll
 - I changed the interface to add some calculator functions: Add / Subtract / Multiply / Divide

In this step I host the service as a console application. Need to run visual studio as Administrator for this.

Add a Console App to the solution, and add the following code. For simplicity I removed exception handling.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Step 1 Create a URI to serve as the base address.  
    Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/WcfGettingStarted/");

    // Step 2 Create a ServiceHost instance  
    using (ServiceHost myHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService), baseAddress))
    {
        // Step 3 Add a service endpoint. 
        var addedServiceEndPoint = myHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
            typeof(ICalculator),
            new WSHttpBinding(),                                                    
            "CalculatorService");                                                   

        // Step 4 Enable metadata exchange.  
        ServiceMetadataBehavior serviceMetaDataBehaviour = new ServiceMetadataBehavior
        {
             HttpGetEnabled = true,
        };
        myHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceMetaDataBehaviour);

        // Step 5 Start the service.  
        myHost.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("The service is running.");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to terminate service.");
        Console.ReadKey();

        // Close the ServiceHostBase to shutdown the service.  
        myHost.Close();
    }
}
```

**Now if you read this code, what would be the address of the calculator service?**

According to the "How-To" it should be:

```
http://localhost:8000/WcfGettingStarted/CalculatorService
```

Yet, if I add this address in my browser (after I started the debugger), it says (in my language) "Deze pagina werkt niet" (This page does not work?). It is a different text than if the service is not running, or if I try a different address.

**Question: Does this mean I have the correct address? Should I expect: this page does not work?**

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a ServiceHost with baseAddress as the Uri, and later add the serviceMetaDataBehaviour to the ServiceHost. There is no link between the service endpoint and the metadata endpoint.

You should be able to visit the metadata endpoint in your browser on http://localhost:8000/WcfGettingStarted/

giving the Metadata endpoint the full url of your service will also work

```
ServiceMetadataBehavior serviceMetaDataBehaviour = new ServiceMetadataBehavior
{
    HttpGetEnabled = true,
    HttpGetUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/WcfGettingStarted/CalculatorService")
};
```